# Convert Byte To String

Tags: c#

I would like to convert a byte to a string.

Example:

```
byte testByte = 0x05;
```

testByte should be converted to "00000101"

I have tried Convert.ToString(testByte, 2), but it only returns "101"

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have tried.

Comment: That's a homework assignment, no prof programmer ever does that.  They use hex.  And use the debugger to display it.  Right click, turn on the checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close already all you need to do is call `PadLeft` on the resulting `String` that you have already:

```
Convert.ToString(testByte, 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
```

Comment: If you are looking for simplicity by all means go with this. On the other hand if you want to fit in with the *"cool programmers"* you have to choose my answer. *:)*

Answer (score -1):

```
static string ToBase2String(int n, int pad)
{
    var s = n < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var v = n < 0 ? -n : n;

    while (v > 0)
    {
        s = (v % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1") + s;
        v /= 2;
    }

    return s.PadLeft(pad, '0');
}
```